# Text with cracks and a different material inside

Tags: modeling, materials

[image: text]

Hello everyone,

how would you recommend to do something like in the attached picture?
Basically a roundish text with some sort of cracks and a different material inside.

I guess a way would be to use a bezier curve with Bevel depth, converting it into a mesh, sculpting the cracks, duplicating it to make a second object with a different material, using boolean to make the missing parts

Do you know better ways?

Comment: i think, the most "impressive" idea would be, to have a soft body inside (which you blow up) until the cloth body outside bursts.... ;)

Answer (score 2):

As you say you could use a *Boolean* modifier to create the cut:

- Create your 2 cylinders, give them materials, *Curve* and *Subdivision Surface* modifiers:

[image]

- Create the boolean object, it's a subdivided cylinder with a *Displace* modifier:

[image]

- Give your orange object a Boolean modifier, put it on the top of the modifiers stack:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer! ;)